# Win10 IoT Screen Orientation Wont Change for Raspberry Pi 3 + RPi 7" Display

Tags: display, windows-iot

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 connected to a Raspberry PI 7" LCD Display. Everything works great with the latest 1607 IoT Core update. However, when attempting to change the Screen Orientation for Windows IoT Core using the web portal (http://{ip address}:8080) for the device it just won't save the change.

When I change the dropdown for the Screen Orientation from the default of Landscape to any other value (Portrait, Landscape (flipped), etc) the portal says the change is saved, but when it restarts the device the screen orientation remains the default Landscape no matter what.

I assume this is a bug in Windows IoT Core, but perhaps there a different way I can change the Screen Orientation. Perhaps from the console or something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I used:

https://www.pedrolamas.com/2016/04/29/changing-the-raspberry-pi-touch-display-rotation-in-windows-10-iot/

Here is another one:

https://buildazure.com/2016/08/06/fix-windows-iot-core-raspberry-pi-touchscreen-display-upside-down/#content-wrapper

Comment: Seems I forgot to post my solution. Well, it's the buildazure.com link. Thanks for posting. :)

Comment: Note that while your links are spot on, you should consider including the key information (i.e. "include `lcd_rotate=2` in `config.txt`") in your answer, because links may go off-line in the future.

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed in OS version 10.0.14393.576.

Please update to this Windows IOT version and you don't need a workarround anymore.